# Cannot import PIL Image

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, python-import

I just wanted to try a chunk of code to paste an image on top of another. Well, I cant go much further as an `AttributeError` is raised right on the import.

```
from PIL import Image

# image_path = "/Users/me/images/"
# fg_file = "hello-600x600.jpg"
# bg_file = "deer-1.jpg"
#
# bg = Image.open(image_path + bg_file)
# fg = Image.open(image_path + fg_file)
#
# bg.paste(fg, (10, 10), fg)
# bg.show()
```

With the import I got the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/dev/pyExamples/image_manipulation/merge_images.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 31, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 206, in <module>
    _lock = threading.RLock()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RLock'
Exception AttributeError: '_shutdown' in <module 'threading' from '/Users/me/dev/pyExamples/threading/__init__.pyc'> ignored

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I seems to come from the method `threading.RLock()` but I don't know what to do here.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Interesting. Does `import thread` work on your system? What about `import threading; print threading.RLock`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
'/Users/me/dev/pyExamples/threading/__init__.pyc'
```

This part of the exception suggests that you have a module called threading in your code. The [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module however is part of the standard library and by creating a module called threading, you are practically overriding the standard one. And so PIL is looking for methods and classes that are not there. You will have to rename the threading module in your code to something else and everything should work fine.

Comment: Perfect! I had never paid any attention to this kind of potential issue. Better checking all my package names while I am at it. Thanks!